# Get JSON page content with PhantomJS

Tags: json, phantomjs

I would like to know how to parse JSON in phantomjs. Any page content is enclosed in html (`<html><body><pre>{JSON string}</pre></body></html>`). Is there an options to remove enclosing tags or asking for a different Content-Type as "application/json"? If not, what's the best way to parse it. Is it using jQuery after including with includeJS jQuery?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since you are using PhantomJS which is built of the webkit browser you have access to the native JSON library. There is no need to use page.evaluate, you can just use the plainText property on the page object.

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/plain-text.html

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://somejsonpage.com', function () {
    var jsonSource = page.plainText;
    var resultObject = JSON.parse(jsonSource);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Shameless plug: Checkout how to use a AWS Lambda to run your phantomjs scripts!
https://github.com/justengland/phantom-lambda-template

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
var obj = page.evaluate(function() {
    return eval('(' + document.body.innerText + ')');
}
```

Then the obj you got is the JSON object returned from that page.

Comment: the obj is null. This code is fine and logs JSON : page.open(encodeURI(url), function(status){
  if( status !== "success"){
    ...
  } else {
      console.log( page.content );
      phantom.exit(); } but not this one : page.open(encodeURI(url), function(status){  if( status !== "success"){ ... } else {     
      var obj = page.evaluate(function() {       
         return eval('(' + document.body.innerText + ')');
      });
      console.log(obj)
      phantom.exit(); page.evaluate is still mysterious! Shouldn't eval be discarded?

Answer (score -1):

As already in the accepted answer, I would suggest using `JSON.parse()` for converting a JSON string into an object.

For example, your code could look like this:

```
var jsonObject = page.evaluate(function() {
  return JSON.parse(page.plainText);
});
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted, this is a valid approach. I know that jQuery might be a little overkill for JSON parsing, but please give me the courtesy of explaining your downvote. Thanks.

Comment: @CameronTinker why not use native javascript JSON.parse ?? Why include a library thats not required for this?

Comment: I have updated this answer to remove jQuery as a dependency.

Answer (score -1):

If the json data contains html strings, they will be removed within the suggested `page.plainText` attribute.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't remove html strings from json.