# PhantomJs- Call WebService & Get data from that

Tags: web-services, phantomjs

I use by PhantomJs for connect to my WebService and **Post** data to *WebService's Function* for special computing.  But i can't get result from *WebService's Function*.

***bin.js:***

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var data = {
    'str': 'sample string'
};
page.open('http://127.0.0.1/Service.asmx/HelloWorld', 'POST', data, function(status) {
    // Get status
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    // I want to get result
    phantom.exit();
});
```

***webService.asmx:***

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(string str)
{
  return str;
}
```

> I want something look like this in PhantomJs:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/Service.asmx/HelloWorld',
    data: {data: 'somethings'},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var result= data.d;
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JSON page content with PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878839/get-json-page-content-with-phantomjs)

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm h.ganjyar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267191/phantomjs-open-page-with-localstorage-by-default),
I can't ask any question. I want to get returned data from WebService.

Comment: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Tahnks, "Get JSON page content with PhantomJS" isn't my answer. I edited my Question. please that.

Comment: The answer says that you can access `page.plainText` to get the response. Have you tried it? What's the problem then?

Comment: I tried it and result wasn't "Hello World". It was like :

Stripped down page text:
Service

The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the Service Description.

HelloWorld
This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default namespace.

Recommendation: Change the default namespace before the XML Web service is made public.

Each XML Web.....

Comment: Are you sure that this endpoint supports POST requests? It doesn't seem to me that this question is about PhantomJS.

Comment: I want by PhantomJs call a WebService and get returned Data. Who I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with search about "phantomjs in c#".

My solution is use of [NReco.PhantomJS](http://www.nrecosite.com/phantomjs_wrapper_net.aspx) library in c#.

Comment: Which property did you use to get the response from service calls made via phantomjs?

Answer (score 1):

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var postBody = 'param1=value1&param2=value2';

page.open('http:www.myservice.com/service', 'POST', postBody, function(status) {
  console.log('Status: ' + status);
  console.log('HTML Content: ' + page.content); // in case of an HTML response
  console.log('JSON: ' + JSON.parse(page.plainText)); // in case of a JSON response
});
```